# How to get popup windows on clicking menu item?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm new to Android App development and java and I have the following problem:
I have an "about" option inside menu in actionbar. I want  popup to appear when clicked on "about" option, showing app version and developer details. As I have no experience with android app development and java(I'm still learning though), could you please help me!

### popup_window.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="133dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="126dp"
    android:text="@string/appVersion" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="156dp"
    android:text="@string/developer" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    // create an action bar button
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    // handle button activities
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.about) {
            // about app page
            onButtonShowPopupWindowClick();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onButtonShowPopupWindowClick(View view) {
        //inflate layout of popup window
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null);

        // creating the popup window
        int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        boolean focusable = true; // lets taps outside the popup also dismiss it
        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);

        // show the popup window
        // which view you pass in doesn't matter, it is only used for the window tolken
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        // dismiss the popup window when touched
        popupView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                popupWindow.dismiss();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this : **https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs** is a good guide for you to start. It also exposes good practices with pop-up in android

Hope it will be helpfull

PS: In the bottom you will find an example with an custom  pop-up like you need

Answer (score 0):

You should try with an AlertDialog:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setView(R.layout.popup_window)
                .create().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `AlertDialog` with a custom view. With a custom view you can design your `AlertDialog` by XML.

```
public void onButtonShowPopupWindowClick(Context context) {
LayoutInflater layoutinflater = getLayoutInflater;
View view1 = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);

AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder1.setCancelable(true);
builder1.setView(view1);
AlertDialog alert = builder1.create();
alert.show();
}
```

You have to create a XML file named *yourlayout* and in this layout you design your dialog.

The Parameter `context` of the void has to be `YourActivity.this`.

Answer (score 0):

just need context (this) or (.context), custom layout with options and find the view(button) the popup will be actived -> translate to java

```
     button.setOnClickListener{
            
            val popup = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_custom_popupmenu, null)
            val popupMenu  = PopupWindow(this)
            popupMenu.contentView = popup
            popupMenu.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            popupMenu.isFocusable = true
            popupMenu.isOutsideTouchable = true

            var op1 = popup.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.popOption1)
            var op2 = popup.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.popOption2)
            var op3 = popup.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.popOption3);
            var op4 = popup.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.popOption4);

            op1.setText("Edit"); op2.setText("Erase")

            op1.setOnClickListener {  popupMenu.dismiss()}
            op2.setOnClickListener { popupMenu.dismiss();}

            popupMenu.setBackgroundDrawable(null)

            popupMenu.showAsDropDown(button, 0, 0)
        }
```